# How to clone a single file from git repository using JGIT

Tags: java, jgit

I have used below code to clone my repository and it works fine.

```
  public static void getCodeBase() throws Exception 
     {
        String url="https://urltogitrepository";
        String destination = ".//clone3//";   
        Git.cloneRepository().setURI(url)
              .setDirectory(Paths.get(destination).toFile()).call();
        System.out.println("Cloned successfully....");

     }
```

But I just want to download a single java file from the git repository instead of cloning the entire repo. But not sure how can I do that.

Comment: Are you looking for `TreeWalk` or `RevWalk` to check on a given repository or do you have an option to get download only the `raw` contents of the file in the git repository?

Comment: Right now the code clone the entire repo. I don't wanna clone all of them only selected file I wanna do. probably config or excel file which is available in that repository. that's my requirement.

Comment: Git repositories (like most other distributed SCM systems) require a local copy of the repository in order to access the contents. Hence the clone step that you posted in your question is necessary.

Comment: Its really helpful. but I have a time constrain to clone the entire files in repo. Its taking more than 8 - 10 minutes most of the times. that's why checking is there any possibility to clone only a file which has 100kb size.

Comment: Instead of cloning the entire repository, you might be interested in using REST API to get the raw content of a single file. For example, [GitHub Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) or [GitLab Repository files API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repository_files.html) allows you to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works fine for me :

```
Git repo = Git.cloneRepository()
          .setURI(url)
          .setDirectory(destination))
          .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/master"))
          .setCloneAllBranches(false)
          .setCloneSubmodules(true)
          .setNoCheckout(true)
          .call();

         repo.checkout().setStartPoint("origin/master").addPath("file1.txt").call();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question with just code, try to explain it a little bit.